# Is the the set of real numbers in the interval $[0,1]$ whose decimal containing only $0$ and $1$ digits countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, real-numbers

I have tried to enumerate this into a list but it does not seem possible.

e.g.: you could have [0,1000 ; 0,1100 ; 0,11100... ; ...]
but then it would be impossible to have
[0,0100... ; 0,01100... ; 0,0011100...]
etc.

There doesn't seem to be an enumeration that contains all possible elements of the set, therefore it isn't countable.

Is this correct?

Thank you.

Comment: You are correct in thinking that it is uncountable, but inability to find an enumeration doesn’t actually prove this. However, it’s not hard to find a bijection between your set and the set of all subsets of $\Bbb Z^+$, for instance.

Comment: You are correct that it isn't countable but your argument seems to be "I tried to list them all but couldn't figure out how to do it so I guess it can't be done".  That's not at all acceptable.  If you can't find a way to list them you must either prove there *can't* be one.

Comment: After all if the rational numbers we could enumerate them in a list and $\frac 12, \frac 13, \frac 14, \frac 15$ etc. but then it's impossible to have $\frac 23, \frac 25$ etc not to mention those with numeror $3$.  So it doesn't seem to be possible so the rationals are uncountable.  Well, just because one method failed doesn't mean another won't work.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott By finding a bijection from the set of all subsets of Z+ to this set, wouldn't that make this set countable? I seem to be missing something obvious... Do you mean that it shouldn't be hard to find a function that maps these two sets?

Comment: And what about $0.1000, 0.0100000, 0.110000, 0.001000, 0.1010....., 0.0110... 0.1110000$ etc.  That seems like we *can*!  So can we or can't we?  Just trying and say it "looks" ok or "looks" impossible is not enough.

Comment: The set of all subsets of $\mathbb Z$ *isn't* countable.  But that' not an obvious result

Comment: @diagoot: $\Bbb Z^+$ has uncountably many subsets, so a bijection between your decimals and the subsets of $\Bbb Z^+$ would show that you have uncountably many decimals. Have you seen any proofs of the uncountability of some set?

Comment: @fleablood I understood your point already, it is why I am asking how to find proof for my intuition.

Comment: Prime mover has a good idea. You can prove that there is a bijection between this set and a set you *know* is uncountable will prove it is uncountable.  Hint... All the numbers that can be written with $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ in base $10$ is all the reals.  ANd all the number that can be written with $0,1$ in base $2$ are all the reals.  So what if we took all the numbers that can be rewritten in base $10$ with just $0,1$ and mapped them into all ther numbers that can be written with just $0,1$ in base $2$?

Comment: How did you prove that the reals were not countable? Can you modify that proof?

Comment: @diagoot The set of all subsets of $\mathbb Z^+$ is very very much uncountable. It's the powerset of $\mathbb Z^+$. The cardinality of the powerset is always of a larger cardinality than that of a set. Set theory 101.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The only proof of uncountability I have seen in my textbook so far is the one for the set of real numbers.

Comment: @diagoot: Did that use a diagonal argument? Because if so, you can use a very similar argument here.

Comment: @PrimeMover Oh wow, that makes sense. I was visualizing in my head the powerset of Z+ as {$\emptyset$, {0}, {0,1}, {0,1,2} ...}... Which made it seem like it could be enumerated...

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, the +1 on the diagonal. Do you mean that, if I +1 on the 1, it becomes a 0?

Comment: @diagoot: Yes, that sounds like you probably have the right idea. If the $n$-th number in your list is $0,b_1b_2b_3\ldots$, make the $n$-th digit of the number that you’re building $1-b_n$, so that it disagrees in the $n$-th place with the $n$-th number in your list.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see it now!! Thank you.

Comment: @diagoot: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a bijection from these numbers to the set of binary reals between $0$ and $1$ in an extremely obvious manner.

Comment: I don't think "extremely obvious" is accurate. I assume (which might be incorrect) you are alluding to the following map: a real with decimal expansion $(0.x_1x_2x_3\ldots)_{10}$ (where $x_n \in \{0,1\}$ for each $\geq 1$) is sent to the real with binary expansion $(0.x_1x_2x_3\ldots)_2$. This is not a bijection. It is surjective but not injective -- consider $(0.1000000\ldots)_{10}$ and $(0.01111111\ldots)_{10}$. The 'obvious' map from this subset of $[0,1]$ to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ corrects this (unless $1$ is being considered an element of this subset of $[0,1]$).

Comment: @Hayden Surjectivity is enough for uncountability, however.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Definitely, but as written this answer doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @Hayden If OP is at the level as to be able to figure out that distinction, they will at least have the insight to see the big picture: "oh yes of course they can't be countable", and if not, then it won't really matter because it will be a whoosh. It does answer the question, because it provides exactly that insight into *why* the numbers shown are uncountable.

Comment: What is this 'obvious' mapping you guys speak of?? Now I'm really feeling stupid...

Comment: @PrimeMover Or they may leave more confused than they already were with less confidence since it is supposedly 'extremely obvious'.

Comment: @diagoot Map $0.1_{10}$ to $0.1_2$, $0.001_{10}$ to $0.001_2$, $0.1111_{10}$ to $0.1111_2$ etc. Just like that. Except as Hayden says, there are binary numbers which are the same $0.1 = 0.0111111....$ which are not the same in decimal, so it's not really a bijection.

Comment: @diagoot They're saying to take the string of digits and interpret it as a binary number. If a real number $x \in [0,1]$ has digits $a_0,a_1, a_2, ...$ with each $a_i$ either $0$ or $1$, then $x = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty a_i 10^{-i}$, and we define $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i 2^{-i}$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma But it is the fact that while $(0.100000 \ldots)_{10} \ne (0.011111 \ldots)_{10}$, we have that $(0.100000 \ldots)_2 =(0.011111 \ldots)_2$ which means that the mapping is not a bijection, as $f ((0.100000 \ldots)_{10}) = f ((0.011111 \ldots)_{10})$. Not an injection.

Comment: Use decimal representation, not binary. Then the OP's set is in bijection with the powerset of $\Bbb N$. So size continuum (even better than just uncountable).

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Yes I get that, you can do it that way. But what I was alluding to was the mapping where you can directly create a mapping from the set in question to $\mathbb R$ by identifying $[0.dddd]_{10}$ with $[0.dddd]_2$ which is a more intuitively "obvious" demonstration of the uncountability of that set than relying upon the knowledge of OP that the powerset of $\mathbb N$ is uncountable -- which at the level of OP, it is not, as this appears not to have been covered in his learning.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma (continued) I'm aware of your own approach, after all, I wrote such a proof myself: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Real_Numbers_are_Uncountable/Set-Theoretical_Approach:_Proof_2

Comment: @PrimeMover The proofwiki proof also should have used decimal expansion, not binary. No case distinctions are needed and we have a direct injection of the powerset into the reals (or $[0,1)$).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma But a decimal expansion would have given the number as strings of integers between 0 and 9. The characteristic function has a range of 0 and 1 which coincides exactly with the binary digits. So expressing a number in binary makes it exactly map onto an element of the power set of $\mathbb N$ via the characteristic function. If you express your real number in decimal there is no such easy mapping.

Comment: @PrimeMover We only want an injection! (from the power set into the relas, in the cardinality proof) And the OP's set only considers reals with this limited options for decimal digits, it's a set (like the Cantor set) that is uncountable and has no interior in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma So we've got an injection, the one that I set up in the first place. Where's the problem?

Comment: @PrimeMover your function is *not* an injection. That's the whole point.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma No you're right, I'm confused, but does it matter? Nor is yours an injection.

Comment: @PrimeMover Mine *is* an injection (from the powerset into the OP's set, which is enough). You show a *surjection* onto $[0,1]$ which both prove what the OP wanted, but then just claim ontoness not a bijection (reread your answer) and surjection is enough.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is a subset of $\Bbb N$ define the number $f(A)$ in your set setting the $n$-th digit in $f(A)$ to $1$ iff $n \in A$. Or in a short formula $$f(A)_n = \chi_A(n)$$

where $\chi_A$ is the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $A$. 
Then $A \to f(A)$ is a bijection between your set and the powerset of $\Bbb N$, which has the same size as $\Bbb R$ and which is uncountable by Cantor's theorem ($|X| < |\mathscr{P}(X)|$ for all $X$).